# About Access Restriction of Web App on Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

Hereafter, the Speadsheet Service [? M$ SQL Server?] will be referred to as "SS".

**background**:
Many companies use SSs as databases for their applications, but they are less conscious of protecting them. Give all employees editing rights to your SS, and take the risk of an unwary user accidentally editing your SS (e.g. inserting a column).

**What I want to achieve:**
I want to reduce the risk of incorrect editing of the SS without using AppSheet (because it is charged).
Specifically, general users cannot directly overwrite the sheet on the SS, but they can overwrite the information in the SS by displaying the form from GAS bound to the SS and submitting the form.

**What I've tried:**

1. Made it so that only the owner can edit the sheet
2. Prepared a web app that edits the SS in a standalone script separate from the SS.
   (The executor is the owner, and the users who can access it are "persons in the organization")

```html
function doPost(e) {
  const SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('*************************************');
  const SHEET = SS.getSheetByName('sheetname');
  SHEET.getRange('A1').setValue(e.parameter.text);
}
```

2. Bind the following script to the SS.
   Prepare a form for registration/update/deletion, and send a post request to the web application

[code.gs]

```html
const SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const APP_URL = "--the endpoint of doPost function--";

function onOpen(e) {
  SS.addMenu(
    'Menu',
    [{name : 'showForm', functionName : 'showForm'}]
  );
}

function showForm(){
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Title');
}


function processForm(formObject) {

  const text = formObject.text;
  
  const params = {
    'method': 'post',
    'payload' : {
      'text': text
    },
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  }
  
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(APP_URL, params);
}
```

[form.html]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      // Prevent forms from submitting.
      function preventFormSubmit() {
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
        for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
          forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });
        }
      }
      window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

      function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).processForm(formObject);
      }
      function onSuccess(){
        google.script.host.close();
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
      <input name="text" type="text" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Issue encountered:**
Because I limited the users who can access the web app (doPost function) to "people in the organization", requests from GAS to the web application was rejected.
But the users who can access the web app should not to be "All" because of security.

Can you please tell me how to teach the doPost func that the user is in the organization?
Or if you know other ways to achieve my purpose, please tell me.

Comment: You are the owner of Spreadsheet and you want to edit the Spreadsheet by your Web Apps while you don't want to directly edit your Spreadsheet by other users. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, I have 2 questions. 1. In your Web Apps, how is your Spreadsheet edited using Web Apps? 2. Are you required to show directly your Spreadsheet to users? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I will answer the question.

1-> I will add detailed process or code to original question text.

2 ->
yes. I've already had success with how to do it in my app, including not only Add/Delete/Update operations, but also list browsing.
However, this time, I'm looking for a way to browse the list in a spreadsheet and use a form only for Add/Delete/Update operations.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding your script. First, I would like to confirm my understanding of your question. You are the owner of Spreadsheet and you want to edit the Spreadsheet by your Web Apps while you don't want to directly edit your Spreadsheet by other users. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: About your added script, I have 2 questions. 1. Where is the function `doPost` and the script `code.gs` and the HTML `form.html`? I cannot understand their relationship of them. 2. About your added script, what is `APP_URL` of `UrlFetchApp.fetch(APP_URL, params);` in the function `processForm`? If that is the endpoint of `doPost`, are you required to send the data using the fetch API?

Comment: (Don't apologise for what you are, or consequences thereof. Invest due effort, and ignore everyone arriving here perfect, if not better.) Please check/correct the introduction of `SS`.

Comment: Tanaike-san ) thank you for your reply. Yes, your understanding is correct. My organizat

Comment: Tanaike-san)1. Where is the function doPost and the script code.gs and the HTML form.html? I cannot understand their relationship of them. -------------> code.gs & form.html is in GAS binded to the spreadsheet. doPost is in a stand-alone app.

Comment: Tanaike-san) 2. About your added script, what is APP_URL of UrlFetchApp.fetch(APP_URL, params); in the function processForm? If that is the endpoint of doPost, are you required to send the data using the fetch API?--------> APP_URL is the endpoint of doPost. (I forgot to paste APP_URL difinition yesterday. Sorry.) First, I tried to use <form action="***" method="post">...</form> to send the request. But It was denied by the browser. So, I tried to use the fetch API.

Comment: greybread-san) Thank you for fixing !

Comment: @miwa Thank you for replying. I noticed from your reply just now. I apologize for this. From your reply, in your situation, for example, can you include `doPost` in the same Google Apps Script project of `code.gs & form.html`? Although, unfortunately, I cannot know your actual environment, I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue. So, I would like to propose trying this modification. But, if this was not the direct solution to your current issue, I apologize.

Comment: @miwa By the way, when you reply to the comment when you add `@` to the top of the user name like `@username`, the user can notice your reply comment.

Comment: @tanaike Thank you for replying. I am sorry for not replying over the weekend. I tried to include doPsot in the same project of code.gs & form.html. But I failed to call doPost again. When I set the access user to "ALL", I succeeded. But when I set it to "PEOPLE IN MY ORGANIZATION" or "PEOPLE IN MY ORGANIZATIOIN", I failed.

Comment: @miwa Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not the direct solution of your issue, I would like to recommend asking the administrator.

Comment: @tanaike Thank you for replying. I tried the way you proposed. But could not call doPost function from form directly. Maybe I misunderstood your thought. I attached my spreadsheet link.Apologize for giving only viewing privileges. Can you please copy to your drive to view my GAS or request edit permission? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X6oR9-a9Si-e-9t6oGQuaiGKvrNV4aTHJJjhoqOdUcs/edit#gid=0

Comment: @miwa Thank you for replying. Now, I posted a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your modifying. I tried your script, but It did not work when another account execute because the target sheet is protected so that only the owner can  edit it directly. I think my initial question was not good. I will post new question after organize my mind. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't notice `I tried your script, but It did not work when another account execute because the target sheet is protected so that only the owner can edit it directly.` from your question. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. In this case, I think that my answer was not useful. So, I have to delete my answer. I apologize for my poor English skill again.